# Convert time based on iso country code local time to utc time in android

Tags: android

Suppose , I have got time as `2018-08-08T00: 00: 00` and I have got iso code `IN` . Now what I want to do is , I want to convert time based on that country code to utc server time. To do that i have written the following method:

```
try {
           Date dateFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strFrom);
           long millisecondsFrom = dateFrom.getTime();
           Date dateTo = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strTo);
           long millisecondsTo = dateTo.getTime();
           long milliseconds = millisecondsTo - millisecondsFrom;
           int msDiff = (int)milliseconds/1000;
           return msDiff;
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Somehow , it is not full-filling my purpose, so is there any way through which I can do that?

Comment: what if you get the code `RU` (russia)? do you know that there are 11 time zones in russia?

Comment: You only can convert from a time zone to another not from country ISO code to a timezone because there are countries that have multiple time zones

Comment: @AhmedHegazy if not, can I get timezone based on particular iso code of a country?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setTimeZone(timeZone); // Timezone is the Timezone the of the time you want to parse

try {
    Date d = df.parse(date);
    // TODO: Do something with the date

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```